# Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'refreshControl'

Tags: swift3

## Making `Refreshable` Protocol

```
import UIKit

protocol Refreshable {
    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl { get }

    func setUp()
}

extension Refreshable where Self: UIViewController {
    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl {
        return UIRefreshControl()
    }
    
    func setUp(_ target: Any?, targetView: UIView, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents) {
        refreshControl.addTarget(target, action: action, for: controlEvents)
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            targetView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else {
            // If targetView is TableView, no need addSubView. Just set refreshControl.
            targetView.addSubview(refreshControl)
            targetView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        }
    }
}
```

## Error

> Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'refreshControl'
>
> Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'alwaysBounceVertical'

## Question

I know `UIView` has no `refreshControl` and `alwaysBounceVertical`.

What Type has those?

Can I pass `targetView` for `UITableView`, `UICollectionView` and `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

You sholud cast `targetView` to `UIScrollView`, `UITableView` or `UIScrollView`

```
if let view = targetView as? UIScrollView{
   view.refreshControl = refreshControl
   //Other processes
}
```